# How to read a value of specific field in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
Template.CompanyEntry.helpers({
    companies: function() {
      var Company= Companies.find();
      console.log (Company); 
      var id = Company._id; 
      Session.set('CurrentCompany',id); 
      alert (Session.get('CurrentCompany')); 
      return Company; 
    }
})
```

I am trying to read specific value from a document. How can I do it?

Comment: `.find()` returns a cursor `.find().fetch()` makes that an array. You have no query conditions so this matches everything, but any `.find()` will match more than one thing. You probably want a query condition and `.findOne()` instead.

Comment: so how I can retrieve only the _id field?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

`var CompanyId = Companies.findOne({TargetName: TargetValue}, {fields: {_id: 1});
var id = CompanyId._id;`

or if you don't want to use findOne, since find is more efficient

`var CompanyArray = Companies.find({TargetName: TargetValue}, {fields: {_id: 1}, limit: 1}).fetch();
var id = CompanyArray[0]['_id'];`